# OpenLayers: Finding features in pixels radius

Tags: openlayers

I'm using openLayers 3.19.1.

When clicking on the map  (map.on("click") event ) I retrieve the pixel I clicked on (event.pixel).

I need to get all features in an X radius on the pixel.

There is a function called "forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent"  I can execute on the ol.source.Vector, but it needs an "extent" parameter.

How can i convert my pixel to an extent?

If anyone has another idea for getting all features in a specific radius of a click on the map please share.

Answer (score 1):

This function answers my question:

```
public  generateExtentFromPixel(pixel: ol.Pixel, size = 100): ol.Extent {

   let EXTENT_TL = [];
   EXTENT_TL[0] = pixel[0] - size;
   EXTENT_TL[1] = pixel[1] - size;

   let EXTENT_BR = [];
   EXTENT_BR[0] = pixel[0] + size;
   EXTENT_BR[1] = pixel[1] + size;

   let newExtent: ol.Extent = [EXTENT_TL[0], EXTENT_TL[1], EXTENT_BR[0], EXTENT_BR[1]];

   return newExtent;
}
```